# Solar power to USB C PD

Tags: power-supply, solar-cell, usb-pd

I want to convert direct sunlight energy into usb c pd.
USB C Pd then will be used to charge a powerbank. 
The bank can be charged via USB C.

The actual solar panel is this: https://www.amazon.de/Powertraveller-ptl-fls021-21-Faltbares-Multi-Spannung-Solarpanel-Black/dp/B07BJNRX9H

Now it has a normal USB A which gives me 5V.
But it also has a standard jack output which is rated to 20V.

I believe using a nice clever approach this 20V could be converted into USB C PD.

I know small modules which can get 20V from a type C port.
Is there anything for the opposite direction? I.e. Generating the power for end-devices.

Comment: Your question is not totally clear. If you specify source and target voltages it will help. I assume "the opposite direction" is 20V to eg 5V from context. You can DIY such from scratch BUT you can but them on ebay or amazon or aliexpress for rather less than you can make them. Look for buck converters. Look at Vin range and Vout range and power level. That PV panel is "OK" compared to some alternatives BUT is far more costly than you can do yourself buying separate panels. ||

Comment: Or [this](https://www.amazon.de/Anker-PowerPort-Ladeger%C3%A4t-2-Port-Solarladeger%C3%A4t/dp/B012VQMGCA/ref=sr_1_4?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&keywords=solar+cell&qid=1562850128&s=ce-de&sr=1-4) may suit you.

Comment: MANY ideas [here](https://www.amazon.de/s?k=solar+panel&i=electronics&__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&ref=nb_sb_noss_2)

Comment: No. The thing is that the panel gives 20V dc output and I want to "convert" it into a type c connector. But PD needs difficult negotiation techniques, that's what this question is about.

Comment: No - that's not what your written question is about :-) - but I now undersyand what you intend. I suggest that you add that information with enough data to say what the issue is , and also make the 20V to 5V (requirement explicit. (The links I specified did cover that correctly).

Comment: But PD is able to handle 20V and max 5A on the typeC connector. So I don't want to convert it to 5V :)

Comment: I think it's a great question.  USB PD is about a lot more than just charging cell phones.  The variable voltage means we could use it for many of our household electrical devices.  I'd also be interested in electronics that allow me to create my own solar + battery to USB PD rigs.

Answer (score 1):

There are also adapters available like this one:
MC4 to USB-C 65W PD output adapter - [Link](https://solarpowersupply.de/zubehor/mc4-to-usb-c-65w-pd-output-adapter)

It takes a variable voltage from the solar panel as input and outputs a max. of 65 W (20V, 3.25 A) depending on the power from the panel.

Answer (score 0):

usb-c pd afaik has some IC on both ends that do the charging logic. without it I fear you might just fry whatever you attach to it.....

easier to just get a solar panel with the usb-c pd ic integrated. Like:

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07SW3GZ64/ref=psdc_2407761011_t2_B0785WCZG7?th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07SW3GZ64)

or

https://lifepowr.co/shop/sun20c/

Comment: Yes, it needs electronics for both ends. I've got a small device which use a DC input voltage and puts it onto PD standard. It works, but the main goal was to charge a power bank even when there is no direct sunlight - and it simply does not work. Direct sunlight is always a must? For every solar panel?

Comment: direct sunlight is pretty much required for most. different tech works better with clouds. but always much less than actual direct sunlight. shade from trees/houses or behind windows, indoor ain't gonna give you no juice at all.

Comment: *different tech*, what does it mean? Which are these techs? Thanks

Comment: @Daniel Realistically, if you're going to have clouds or shading, then a rechargeable battery, charged off the solar panel, is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

DeWalt is launching the DCB094 next month which has [bidirectional power supply up to 100W](https://www.theverge.com/2022/1/27/22905482/dewalt-ryobi-milwaukee-usb-c-power-tool-batteries) with any 20V DeWalt Battery. So you could power it from your solar panel and use the bank to discharge that power back to whatever device you choose